# Nested list in Prolog

Tags: prolog

How can I make a nested list like (3 (2 (1) 2) 3) from (3 2 1 2 3) in PROLOG?

There is a condition: it is not allowed to use looping operators, direct access functions to list elements, or high-level list processing operators

it doesn't work properly:

```
nested_list([], []).
nested_list([H|T], [H|[NestedT]]) :-
  nested_list(T, NestedT).
```

Comment: What **is** allowed? Is a [tag:dcg] allowed?

Answer (score 1):

```
palin([]) --> [].
palin([E]) --> [E].
palin([E,I,E]) --> [E], palin(I), [E].

?- phrase(palin(T),[3,2,1,2,3]).
   T = [3,[2,[1],2],3]
;  false.
?- phrase(palin(T),L).
   T = [], L = []
;  T = [_A], L = [_A]
;  T = [_A,[],_A], L = [_A,_A]
;  T = [_A,[_B],_A], L = [_A,_B,_A]
;  T = [_A,[_B,[],_B],_A], L = [_A,_B,_B,_A]
;  T = [_A,[_B,[_C],_B],_A], L = [_A,_B,_C,_B,_A]
;  ... .
```